# maxByOrNull function in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Nowadays I am learning Kotlin and I have a question. In the below code, I did not understand the work done in line 2 and 3. Actually I understood the work done but the code seemed a little complicated to me. Can you explain the code in these lines?

```
data class Item(val name: String, val price: Float)                                         // 1  

data class Order(val items: Collection<Item>)  

fun Order.maxPricedItemValue(): Float = this.items.maxByOrNull { it.price }?.price ?: 0F    // 2  
fun Order.maxPricedItemName() = this.items.maxByOrNull { it.price }?.name ?: "NO_PRODUCTS"  // 3

val Order.commaDelimitedItemNames: String                                                   // 4
    get() = items.map { it.name }.joinToString()

fun main() {

    val order = Order(listOf(Item("Bread", 25.0F), Item("Wine", 29.0F), Item("Water", 12.0F)))
    
    println("Max priced item name: ${order.maxPricedItemName()}")                           // 5
    println("Max priced item value: ${order.maxPricedItemValue()}")
    println("Items: ${order.commaDelimitedItemNames}")                                      // 6

}
```

I would be very happy if you can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is the instance of the `Order`. The `Order` contains a collection of `Item`. Each `Item` contains a `name` and a `price`

That means that this:

```
this.items.maxByOrNull { it.price }?.price ?: 0F
```

translates to:

- In this `Order`, take from the collection the `Item` that contains the biggest `price`.
- If there is an actual `Item` return the `price` of the `Item`
- If there is no actual `Item` in this order, then give me null (and if you give me null, I'll return `0` as a `Float` number)

And this:

```
this.items.maxByOrNull { it.price }?.name ?: "NO_PRODUCTS"
```

translates to:

- In this `Order`, take from the collection the `Item` that contains the biggest `price`.
- If there is an actual `Item` return the `name` of the `Item`
- If there is no actual `Item` in this order, then give me null (and if you give me null, I'll return to `NO_PRODUCTS`)

We get this because:

- The [maxByOrNull](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by-or-null.html) in `items.maxByOrNull {it.price }` will return the `Item` with the biggest price, but if the `items` collection is empty, it will return `null`
- The [safe call](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) `?` means that we only want to do the next process if our value is not null (in our example we only want to return the outcome of `maxByOrNull` if it is not `null`)
- The [elvis operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) `?: something` means that if the previous thing is null, then this `something` is the value you'll get

The whole page for [Null Safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) is quite useful.

Comment: @Alex.T Might as well add the explanation for the extension function too :)